# python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: python-2.7, django-cms, mezzanine

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 28, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cartridge/shop/models.py", line 411, in <module>
    class Order(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cartridge/shop/models.py", line 422, in Order
    billing_detail_country = ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name = _("State/Region"),  related_name='order', limit_choices_to={ "parent":Category.objects.get(slug='regions') }, blank=True, null=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 131, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 361, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 85, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 344, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: shop_category
```

Hello.
 python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:80 not running on server.

In MySQL table shop_category present. In settings.py name DB, login and password configured.
syncdb not solved my problem.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

Comment: "no such table: shop_category": Have you executed `python manage.py syncdb` successfully before running the test server?

Comment: no successfully. "no such table: shop_category":

Comment: From which app should come this table?

Comment: This line is weird in your error:    `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 344, in execute`

why sqlite3 as you say your backend is mysql ? Post your database settings.